# JQuery Validation For Date Field

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm encountering a problem in validating input fields, I have three input fields, one for first name, last name, and date of birth, when I leave the fields empty it shows warning messages as defined in the code, when I enter data into the fields the message disappears except for the date field. It disappears only when I click once again. Here is my code

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head id="html">
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css">
 <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
 <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.3/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
 <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.ui/1.10.4/themes/redmond/jquery-ui.css">
 <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js"> </script>
 <script>
  $(function() {
   $("#date-of-birth").datepicker(
   {
    dateFormat:'dd-mm-yy',
    changeMonth: true,
    changeYear: true,
   }); 
  });
 </script>
 <style >
  #first-name{
   width: 300px;
   margin-top: 10px;
   margin-left: 510px;
   padding-left: 10px;
   border: 1px solid grey;
   border-radius: 5px;
  }
  #last-name{
   width: 300px;
   margin-top: 5px;
   margin-left: 510px;
   padding-left: 10px;
   border: 1px solid grey;
   border-radius: 5px;
  }
  #date-of-birth{
   width: 300px;
   margin-top: 5px;
   margin-left: 510px;
   padding-left: 10px;
   border: 1px solid grey;
   border-radius: 5px; 
  }
  #first-name-warning-message{ 
   padding-left: 640px;
   font-size: 18px;
   font-weight: bold;
  }
  #last-name-warning-message{
   padding-left: 640px;
   font-size: 18px;
   font-weight: bold;
  }
  #dob-warning-message{
   padding-left: 640px;
   font-size: 18px;
   font-weight: bold;
  }
 </style>
</head>
<body id="body">
 <form id="sign-up" action="#" method="post">
  <div id="row-one">
   <input type="text" id="first-name" name="first_name" placeholder="First Name" maxlength="15">
  </div>
  <div id="span-container">
   <span id="first-name-warning-message" class="text-danger"> </span>
  </div>
  <div id="row-two">
   <input type="text" id="last-name" name="last_name" placeholder="Last Name" maxlength="15">
  </div>
  <div id="span-container">
   <span id="last-name-warning-message" class="text-danger"> </span>
  </div>
  <div id="row-three">
   <input class="date-picker" id="date-of-birth" name="user_dob" placeholder="Date Of Birth" readonly="true">
  </div>
  <div id="span-container">
   <span id="dob-warning-message" class="text-danger"> </span>
    </div>
 </form>
 <script>
  $(document).ready(function(){
   $('#first-name-warning-message').hide();
   $('#last-name-warning-message').hide();
   $('#dob-warning-message').hide();

   var first_name_error=true;
   var last_name_error=true;
   var dob_error=true;

   $('#first-name').focusout(function(){
    validate_first_name();
   });

   $('#last-name').focusout(function(){
    validate_last_name();
   });

   $('#date-of-birth').focusout(function(){
    validate_date_of_birth();
   });

   function validate_first_name(){
    var first_name=$('#first-name').val();
    var first_name_regex=/^[a-zA-Z ]{3,15}$/;
    if(first_name.length==''){
     $('#first-name-warning-message').show();
     $('#first-name-warning-message').html("Please Enter Your First Name !");
     first_name_error=false;
     return false;
    }
    else{
     $('#first-name-warning-message').hide();
    }

    if(first_name.length<3){
     $('#first-name-warning-message').show();
     $('#first-name-warning-message').html("First Name Not Valid !");
     first_name_error=false;
     return false;
    }
    else{
     $('#first-name-warning-message').hide();
    }

    if(!first_name_regex.test(first_name)){
     $('#first-name-warning-message').show();
     $('#first-name-warning-message').html("First Name Must Not Contain Any Digits Or Symbols !");
     first_name_error=false;
     return false;
    }
    else{
     $('#first-name-warning-message').hide();
    }
   }

   function validate_last_name(){
    var last_name=$('#last-name').val();
    var last_name_regex=/^[a-zA-Z ]{3,15}$/;

    if(last_name.length==''){
     $('#last-name-warning-message').show();
     $('#last-name-warning-message').html("Please Enter Your Last Name !");
     last_name_error=false;
     return false;
    }
    else{
     $('#last-name-warning-message').hide();
    }

    if(last_name.length<3){
     $('#last-name-warning-message').show();
     $('#last-name-warning-message').html("Last Name Not Valid !");
     last_name_error=false;
     return false;
    }
    else{
     $('#last-name-warning-message').hide();
    }

    if(!last_name_regex.test(last_name)){
     $('#last-name-warning-message').show();
     $('#last-name-warning-message').html("Last Name Must Not Contain Any Digits Or Symbols !");
     last_name_error=false;
     return false;
    }
    else{
     $('#last-name-warning-message').hide();
    }
   }

   function validate_date_of_birth(){
    var date_of_birth=$('#date-of-birth').val();
    if(date_of_birth.length==''){
     $('#dob-warning-message').show();
     $('#dob-warning-message').html("Please Enter Your Date Of Birth !");
     dob_error=false;
     return false;
    }
    else{
     $('#dob-warning-message').hide();
    }
   }
  });
 </script>
</body>
</html>
```

can y'all provide me a solution for this?. All answers are appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: You have focusout event handler for your date input, but when the user wants to select the date he already focuses out. So, I think you should validate on focusout (or on blur). Is there any submit button in your form?

Comment: yeah i've used in my actual code

Comment: So validate the date time when user submits the page. Because when the user clicks on a date in the datepicker it focuses out of the input then your event handler will trigger and says "the text is empty" because we haven't set the date from the calendar in the input.

Comment: A quick fix can be changing  `validate_date_of_birth()` to `setTimeout( validate_date_of_birth, 500)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As your code is currently structured, the `focusout` and `blur` events will both be triggered before the value of `$('#date-of-birth')` has been set. It will not run again after the value is set unless you enter and leave the field again.

Instead of calling your `validate_date_of_birth()` on focusout or blur, consider adding an `onClose` function to your datepicker definition with your validate logic. This way it will not run the validation until the datepicker has closed and a value has been assigned.

i.e.,

```
$(function() {
    $("#date-of-birth").datepicker({
        dateFormat:'dd-mm-yy',
        changeMonth: true,
        changeYear: true,
        onClose: function(selectedDate){
            var date_of_birth=selectedDate;
            if(date_of_birth.length==''){
                $('#dob-warning-message').show();
                $('#dob-warning-message').html("Please Enter Your Date Of Birth !");
                dob_error=false;
                return false;
            }
            else{
                $('#dob-warning-message').hide();
            }
        }
    }); 
});
```

See this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15342360/jquery-datepicker-onclose-select-next) for an example of how `onClose` works, or the [jQuery documentation](http://api.jqueryui.com/datepicker/#option-onClose).